# Is it safe to use a custom value for users.status column

Tags: users, database

Currently `status` column can have only 2 values:

- 0 - inactive
- 1 - active

I need to add a new status for the user: temporarily inactive. Will it be safe if I use `status` = 2 for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long story short: no, never

why: user->status is deep bound into drupal core, so in order to handle status=2 you will have to hack the core

there are alternatives: you could use another field or expand user entity

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to?

You can attach a boolean or numeric field to the user entity.

Navigate to Admin -> Configuration -> Accounts -> Add Field.